# Android: Multiple Sceen layout API

Tags: android, layout

I just want to make sure I'm understanding the method to setup for multiple screen.

I want to make the app runnable from API 8-21.

So far, I implemented smallest-width to differentiate the multiple screen. Everything works perfectly in the emulator when I use API 17, but crashes when i use API 8. I then realized that smallest-width only works for API 13 and above.

So now, I think my next step is to just create layout-small, layout-normal, etc. and adjust it for them.

Is this the correct way to tackle the problem?

Edit***********

Here's the logcat from the error filter, let me know if I need to post the other:

```
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nah.ace/com.nah.ace.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030018
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030018
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.nah.ace.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-19 05:28:37.769: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
```

Also would like to add that my default layout folder is empty. Under API8, it seems like it's trying to load off that folder, instead of layout-sw-320dpi, which is probably the reason for the crash. I tested on API17+API21 and it loads off the layout-sw-320dpi just fine.

Edit2:
Seems to only work on API16+.

Edit3:
My manifest's sdk:

android:minSdkVersion="8"

android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Comment: sorry, give me a bit of time to figure out how to format it cleaner

Answer (score 0):

No , problem is caused by due to your java class not by your xml files what I can assume from this point.

Comment: I'm not too sure if it's the java class. My first main activity only setcontentview to a "menu" layout, and I just set the onclicklistener for buttons, to create a new activity when clicked.

When I created a layout-small, and pasted a menu layout into it, it no longer crashes for the API8 2.7"QVGA.

Comment: Also forgot to ask, is smallest-width suppose to work, regardless of api version?